# Is Revolut travel insurance eligible for only those registered under UK healthcare system?

Tags: insurance, revolut

As a Polish citizen, I'm using Revolut travel insurance. By reading the Help section, there is a note:

> Am I eligible for Revolut travel insurance?
>
> The cover is available provided that you and any travel companion named on the policy are:
>
> - **Residing in the European Economic Area** (EEA)
> - [...]
>
> ([Source](https://www.revolut.com/help/exploring-revolut/insuring-my-travel/am-i-eligible-for-revolut-travel-insurance))

However, when I've read the insurance rules on the Revolut mobile application, it says:

> This cover is available provided that You are:
>
> - [...]
> - **Registered under the healthcare system within Your Home Country (which must be within the United Kingdom)**
> - [...]
>
> ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvdGI.jpg))

**Now, the question is**: Are people which are not registered under the healthcare system within UK, but are residents of the EEA eligible for Revolut travel insurance?

Comment: Have you asked them?

Comment: @Traveller: Yes, but still haven't got an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have an answer from Revolut chat:

> The insurance does cover Polish citizens. The home country can be any from the EEA area.